# Indices and Slicing of TensorFlow's global variables of kernels for hidden weights and recurrent states of LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have a question about detailed indices of global variables which are generated by LSTM cells.

```
placeholders = {"inputs":tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, 1000])}
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(80)
outs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=placeholders["inputs"], dtype=tf.float32)
```

This graph building gives us tf.global_variables() list as follows:

```
[<tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel:0' shape=(1080, 320) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_lstm_cell/bias:0' shape=(320,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

My question is about the index set of the variable 'rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel:0'.
According to the source file of BasicLSTMCell ( https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.5/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L537 ), this variable has two kinds of vectors: the first one is for hidden weights and the second one is for recurrent state.

> Is the following partition of indices of kernel variable correct?
>
> Do hidden weights and recurrent state correspond to tf.slice(var, [0:0], [1000,320] and tf.slice(var, [1000:0], [1080:320]), respectively, where "var" rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel variable?

That is, the first 1000(=the dimenrnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernelsionality of input sequence) indices are for hidden weights and the next 80(=num_units) indices are for recurrent state.

Comment: I haven't ever looked at the variables created by `basic_lstm_cell` before, so I won't post this as an answer unless you validate it. Considering that there are 4 sets of weights in an LSTM cell (`forget gate`, `block input`, `input gate`, `output gate`). And the output of each should be 80, (320/80=4 sets of weights) should be the partition. 1080 should be the concatenation of your input and hidden state size. http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

Comment: Thank you. Yes my question is about not the number of variables, but is the *order of index assignment* of variables. So, I edited the questions.

Comment: I have a feeling your misunderstanding, but maybe I am. The internals of an LSTM are effectively 4x 1-layer fully connected networks which are piped together an interesting way (link describing them in my comment above). I believe you're looking at the weights, though I would have expected them to be 4 separate vars rather than 1, but that's just me. Assuming I'm correct so far, then a standard fully connected weight matrix is `[n_inputs x n_output_neurons]`, this is where I derived my numbers from. The hidden state is computed using the weights, but it is not the weights themselves.